# Treeview.Items.Clear() method return null exception (e.NewValue==null) in SelectedItemChanged Event

Tags: c#, wpf

I am from Iran and I cant speak English very well, sorry.
I made something like `OpenFileDialog` in WinForms
and work correctly.
After, for better user interface, I tried to make it in WPF.
I use `TreeView` and other controls for it in both platforms (Winforms and WPF)
in Winforms I could do this correctly usingbelow code:

```
private void Folder_FileTreeView_NodeMouseDoubleClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
{
    Folder_FileTreeView.Nodes.Clear();//this is necessary to clean first page node, after  get new folders
    if(e.Node.Text=="Desktop")//also this code is necessary to compare node 
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

[image]
Also in WPF I can get text of Item by below code:

```
private void Folder_FileTreeView_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
{
    if (e.NewValue!=null)
    {
        StackPanel CustomStackPanel = (StackPanel)((TreeViewItem)e.NewValue).Header;
        TextBlock textBlock = (TextBlock)CustomStackPanel.Children[1];
        nodetext = textBlock.Text;//this line return text of item for compare
    }
    Folder_FileTreeView.Items.Clear();
}
```

[image]
If I don't use `Folder_FileTreeView.Items.Clear()` the above code return folders without clearing first page, but if I do use `Folder_FileTreeView.Items.Clear()` `e.NewValue` returns `null`.
Please help me to **use together** these codes: **Folder_FileTreeView.Items.Clear();(or clear first page)** and **get text of selecteditem by user without return null**

Thanks A lot

Answer (score 0):

`e.NewItem` will be `null` if the `TreeView` used to have an item selected but now does not. When you clear the items, you are removing any selection, this of course *changes* the selection and raises the `SelectedItemChanged` event with `null` as the new selection- since there are no possible items that *could* be selected.

If you want to replace the items in the list with new items after the user makes a selection, the selected item will be `null` while that change is happening. You need to do the following:

1. Handle the `SelectedItemChanged` event and **remember the new selected item in a variable**.
   For example, if they click on the item for "Desktop" set a variable (e.g. `Path`) to the path for the user's desktop (e.g. C:\Users\UserName\Desktop).
2. Clear the list of folders in the `TreeView`. This will trigger `SelectedItemChanged` again, but you want to **ignore** it this time because `e.NewItem == null`.
3. Read all the folders in `Path` and make new items for each of those folders.

Comment: sorry I cant Understand what you mean exactly can you help me by  edit my code ?

Comment: Maybe, if you can explain a bit more to me. Why are you clearing the `TreeView` after the user selects an item?

Comment: first of all item or node in treeview can merge with icon ,so i use treeview but i dont like showing as tree  i like to show like when clicked in my computer drives item or folder is that showing as tree?(also no).when first page of program(my program)load have some default Item(Desktop,Document,Download,Picture,Network,sample picture)so i want when my user click to any of default item in first page ,first page clear and folders of Deafault item Showing understand?

Comment: are u have whatapp?or have place to chat?

Comment: I do not, but I updated my answer to explain a bit more. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: I think i can make new method instead of clear method if i found it i tell u thank you very much :):):)

Answer (score 0):

The way was found by below code

```
private void Folder_FileTreeView_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
{
    Folder_FileTreeView.SelectedItemChanged -= Folder_FileTreeView_SelectedItemChanged;
    if (e.NewValue!=null)
    {
        StackPanel CustomStackPanel = (StackPanel)((TreeViewItem)e.NewValue).Header;
        TextBlock textBlock = (TextBlock)CustomStackPanel.Children[1];
        nodetext = textBlock.Text;//this line return text of item for compare
    }
    Folder_FileTreeView.Items.Clear();
    Folder_FileTreeView.SelectedItemChanged += Folder_FileTreeView_SelectedItemChanged;
}
```

thank very much for every one helped me